# SQL to consolidate dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following data:

```
rasID   changeDate  changeDateEnd   status
11860   2015-09-08  2015-10-09      Active
11860   2015-10-09  2015-10-19      Planning
11860   2015-10-19  2015-10-19      Planning
11860   2015-10-19  2015-11-18      Planning
11860   NULL        2015-11-18      Planning
11861   2015-09-08  2015-10-09      Planning
11861   2015-10-09  2015-10-12      Requested
11861   2015-10-12  2015-11-18      Planning
11861   NULL        2015-11-18      Planning
```

What I want is to consolidate this data so it looks like this:

```
rasID   changeDate  changeDateEnd   status
11860   2015-09-08  2015-10-09      Active
11860   2015-10-09  2015-11-18      Planning
11861   2015-09-08  2015-10-09      Planning
11861   2015-10-09  2015-10-12      Requested
11861   2015-10-12  2015-11-18      Planning
```

I can't figure out a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is just to ignore `changeDateEnd` and focus on the `changeDate`.  You then want to combine rows that are adjacent.

One method of doing this uses a difference of row numbers with aggregation, something quite suitable in SQL Server 2008:

```
select rasId, min(changeDate), max(changeDate), status
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by rasId order by coalesce(changeDate, getdate()) ) -
              row_number() over (partition by rasId, status order by coalesce(changeDate, getdate()) )
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by rasId, grp,
order by rasId, min(changeDate);
```

The purpose of the `coalesce()` is simply to ensure that `NULL` values go last.  If you have dates in the future, you will want to use a different expression.

Comment: Add `status` to `Group BY`. Anyway you need to tweak your query because it produces different results https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/394721

Comment: @lad2025: Why did you put the ",2" in the order by statement?  And why is it that this did not work until I stuck the ", 2" in the order by?

Comment: @lad2025 . . . I wasn't focused on the actual ordering of the final result set.  The right thing to add is the date, not the status (at least I think the ordering of the status names is only coincidently related to their ordering in the data).

Comment: So tell me how it can work when `status` is not contained in aggregated function and GROUP BY clause?

Comment: I put max(status) in my select.  Seems to give me what I want.